# JasperReports Server: Exporting Data to multiple tabs/sheets in a single Excel file

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

I have tried many suggestions in the forum but could not find a working solution for exporting data to multiple tabs/sheets in a single excel file.

I created the .jrxml using *iReport Designer Pro 5.0.0* and when I preview in *iReport* Report viewer, I can see multiple tabs (each tab is supplied by a different DataSet/Query and the rows are > 10000) as expected.

But when I deploy in *JasperReports Server* and try to export in *Excel* format it gives all the data from two queries/dataset into a single *Excel* tab only. Could anyone send a working example to solve this problem.

I have already tried the Page Break, Line Break, Sub report, Groups, Different properties like ***ignore pagination***, ***net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.one.page.per.sheet***, ***net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.break.after.row*** and ***net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.break.before.row***.

Answer (score 2):

you need to set a property in Jrxml

net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.max.rows.per.sheet

Value : your expected more than 10000 rows right. Give 25000